# How do you hide license key from inspect element for fullpage.js?

Tags: fullpage.js

license key for fullpage.js is exposed just by inspecting element. i've looked through websites using fullpage.js and they managed to hide the license key wonderfully. any idea how they are doing it?

Comment: Activation key is customized for specific domain. You dont need to hide it

Comment: My license key is not domain specific

Answer (score 2):

You can't hide it. Remember all front-end code is by default accesible to any who wants to see it.

The more you can do is obfuscate it and try to make it harder for others to find it. But there's definitely no way to completely hide it.

See [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30501161/javascript-hiding-contents-of-key).

Comment: What happens in the event of theft then?

Comment: The theft will be the one responsible for it and the one violating the law. They could be subject to legal actions against them or their company.